# why the style dosent work until i put directly on the div tag?

Tags: html, css

this is a php file with some html code:

```
<div id="cont_tabla" class="conte_tabla">
        <table width="70%" border='1'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>Modificar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                    <th>Nv1</th>
                    <th>Nv2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and it dosent work with this css file:

```
#cont_tabla {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.conte_tabla {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

but if i do this it works

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
...
</div>
```

the question its why only works when i put the style directly on the div ?

**Edit**

i added a full view of my php/html code and the css

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php
    require 'NuevosVideos.php';
?>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>insertar Nuevo Video</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- style="overflow-x: auto;" -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table width="70%" border='1'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>Modificar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                    <th>Nv1</th>
                    <th>Nv2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

**css**

```
:root {
    --blanco: #b6b6b6;
    --text-secondary: #ececec;
    --negro: #23232e;
    --negro2: #141418;
    --negro_hover: #303030;
    --azul: #3b83bd;
    --verde: #008f39;
    --naranja: #ff8000;
    --cafe: #804000;
    --transition-speed: 600ms;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--negro);
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

it works on the part of the background but not in the rest i dont know what i am missing

Comment: Have you included your CSS in the html file (PHP in your case)

Comment: i have it on the html part but...need i include with php?

Comment: Try adding your css directly to the HTML under the style tags and see if work, if it does then style-sheet import is definitely the problem

Comment: ok i do that and it works but i can tell that the css file its working with things like the background but not with the overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out guys tank you so much for your answers but the problem was the `cache` from the `opera browser` sorry for the time that you spent on answering this

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your css file in head tag of HTML file. If not, please do so by adding below tag in head of html file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your css file path">
```

Comment: yes i actually have it, and yes its in the same folder

Comment: Can you show your head section of html file. I don't see any other problem. There is something wrong with importing the css file maybe.

Comment: @Sole Panic, can you see the styles in the browser object inspector?

Comment: yes you are right i cant see the rest of the css file in the browser object inspector but why it works on the background ?

Comment: @SolePanic You have applied padding, margin also. Are they working? If yes then can you add override property eg: overflow-x: auto !important;. Then check in browser inspector if style is being added now.

Answer (score 0):

You surely haven't included this given code inside the head tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" or your css file name>
```